# Javascript - Input number only by latin and Japanese

Tags: javascript, unicode

How can my input accept only numbers written in latin charset or Japanese:
I googled it but just can get result of latin charset only, not utf-8 supported.

Example: `13` and `１３` is accepted

Comment: You can do this the same way you define any range with regex: `[\d０-９]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use HTML5 pattern validation

```html
<input pattern="[\d\uff10-\uff19]*" />
```

`\d` matches a digit (character in the 0-9 range).

`\uff10-\uff19` matches a character in the ０-９ range.

`*` means zero or more times.